# Цикл не прогоняет значения

Tags: python, функции, циклы

Есть данный цикл в функции.Он должен проверять,в какую категорию входит значение цены и отправлять,соответственно,в данную категорию.Чего он делать отказывается.

```
def Cennosti(R, K, Lin, Last, Popova):
z = [('Ручка', R), ('Карандаш', K), ('Линейка', Lin), ('Ластик', Last), ('Попова Ольга Владимировна', Popova)]
print(z)
g = ""
h = ""
b = ""
for i in z:
    c = type(i[1])
    if c==int and i[1] < 0:
        print("введено неверное значение,введите везде положительные цифры")
    elif c == int and 0 < i[1] < 100:
        g = g + " " + i[0]
        return (g)
    elif c == int and 100 < i[1] < 300:
        h = h + " " + i[0]
        return (h)
    elif c == int and 210 < i[1]:
        b = b + " " + i[0]
        return (b)

print("Дешевыми товарами являются" + g)
print("Товары средней ценовой категории-это" + h)
print("Бесценна же" + b)


R = int(input('R'))
K = int(input('K'))
Lin = int(input('Lin'))
Last = int(input('Last'))
Popova = int(input('Popova'))

Cennosti(R, K, Lin, Last, Popova)
```

Comment: может, оно и к лучшему, что отказывается? )

Comment: Хотелось бы чтобы все же вывел ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку Вы использовали инструкцию `return` при проверке каждого условия, то при истинности любого из них функция сразу же возвращала значение (в примере Вашего кода – это возвращаемое значение было `(g)`, `(h)` или `(b)`) и, соответственно, прекращала свою работу.

Функции – это одни из самых основных программных структур в языке Python, поэтому Вам стоит подробнее изучить назначение основных инструкции и выражений, имеющих отношение к функциям.

Для каждой категории, на мой взгляд, лучше бы использовать список, а не строку. Потому что так удобнее будет обращаться с каждым объектом, особенно, если Вам еще и в дальнейшем понадобится эта классификация по стоимости. Ну, а для печати можно всегда сгенерировать строку с помощью метода строк `str.join(iterable)`.

Не знаю, по какому критерию оценивают бедную Ольгу Владимировну среди канцелярских изделий, но вот мой вариант возможного решения Вашей проблемы:

```
def Cennosti(R, K, Lin, Last, Popova):
    z = [('Ручка', R), ('Карандаш', K), ('Линейка', Lin), ('Ластик', Last), ('Попова Ольга Владимировна', Popova)]
    print(z)
    g = []
    h = []
    b = []
    for item, cost in z:  # item = 'Ручка', cost = R на первой итерации
        c = type(cost)
        if c is int:  # проверку того, что стоимость целое число, можно сделать один раз
            if cost < 0:
                print("Введено неверное значение, введите везде положительные цифры")
            elif 0 < cost < 100:
                g.append(item)
            elif 100 < cost < 300:
                h.append(item)
            elif 210 < cost:
                b.append(item)
        else:
            print("Стоимость должна быть целым числом...")
            return None

    # Если информация о стоимости объектов далее нигде не понадобится, то можно оставить и три print'a;
    # но лучше вернуть все значения (g, h и b), а уже дальше, например, в отдельной функции выводить на печать
    print("Дешевыми товарами являются " + " ".join(i for i in g))
    print("Товары средней ценовой категории-это " + " ".join(i for i in h))
    print("Бесценна же " + " ".join(i for i in b))

    return g, h, b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    R = int(input('R'))
    K = int(input('K'))
    Lin = int(input('Lin'))
    Last = int(input('Last'))
    Popova = int(input('Popova'))

    Cennosti(R, K, Lin, Last, Popova)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы же в цикле *return* делаете, соответственно выходите из функции. Нужно *return* заменить на *continue*

```
def Cennosti(R, K, Lin, Last, Popova):
    z = [('Ручка', R), ('Карандаш', K), ('Линейка', Lin), ('Ластик', Last), ('Попова Ольга Владимировна', Popova)]
    print(z)
    g = ""
    h = ""
    b = ""
    for i in z:
        c = type(i[1])
        if c==int and i[1] < 0:
            print("введено неверное значение,введите везде положительные цифры")
        elif c == int and 0 < i[1] < 100:
            g = g + " " + i[0]
            continue
        elif c == int and 100 < i[1] < 300:
            h = h + " " + i[0]
            continue
        elif c == int and 210 < i[1]:
            b = b + " " + i[0]
            continue

    print("Дешевыми товарами являются" + g)
    print("Товары средней ценовой категории-это" + h)
    print("Бесценна же" + b)


R = int(input('R'))
K = int(input('K'))
Lin = int(input('Lin'))
Last = int(input('Last'))
Popova = int(input('Popova'))

Cennosti(R, K, Lin, Last, Popova)
```